# Running ASP.NET 4.5 site on host that does not support it?

Tags: hosting, asp.net-4.5

I use crystaltech for my sites. Yet they have not installed asp.net 4.5 and as far as i can tell have no plans to do so in the near future. Is it possible to run a ASP.NET 4.5 site on a host that does not yet have it installed by uploading ALL the needed DLLs? Apologies in advance if not seen as constructive and closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do this.  Much of the new 4.5 functionality is provided by the .NET Framework itself, and these binaries (mscorlib.dll, System.dll, System.Web.dll, and others) need to be installed on the machine.  They cannot be dropped in the bin/ folder.